# When does the 'standard' angular velocity formula not hold?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

I have read that the formula for angular velocity:
$$\dot {\vec r}=\vec \omega \times\vec r \tag{1}$$
does not hold in some situations, but the book does not specify what situation so please could you produce a list of when this formula does not hold.

If this formula does not hold is it also true that:
$$\vec \omega= \frac{\vec r \times \vec v}{|\vec r|^2} \tag{2}$$
does not hold?

Comment: Where did you read this? The context might be helpful. Also, I assume your $w$ is meant to be $\omega$ (written `$\omega$` in MathJax)?

Comment: @Floris It was in 'Introduction to classical mechanics' by David Morin, the context is in general circular motion, in 3d.

Comment: I wonder whether this is talking about the situation where $\vec\omega$ is not constant ($\dot{\vec\omega}≠0$) - I think an additional term might appear in that case.

Comment: @Floris I think I am, like when we have a torque acting

Comment: I don't think there is a term for $\dot{\vec{\omega}}\ne0$, but there is a term if your rotating object has a non-zero translational velocity. There could also be a term if your object is doing some motion on top of a rotation. For example if you are driving a car on earth, your velocity relative to the stars is the sum of the earth's velocity, plus the $\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ velocity that comes from earth's rotation, plus your velocity relative to the surface of the earth from you driving the car.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: I edited the OP:  $w \rightarrow \omega$ so that it doesn't look odd to those of us who are used to $\omega$.  @Qmechanic, what do you mean "list question"?

Comment: @garyp: OP wrote: _[...] so please could you produce a list [...]_

Comment: @garyp , list or not list, I believe I answered the question. It's matter of equivalence between the equations (1) and (2) under certain conditions (which probably are trivial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron spin is not the result of a rotation of the electron around itself. In this case, of course (2) also doesn't hold.

In fact, one can show that there is a double implication as follows:

1) if $\vec v$ is defined as in (1) one gets

$$ \frac {\vec r \times \vec v}{r^2} = \vec {\omega} - \vec r \frac {(\vec r \cdot \vec {\omega})}{r^2}. \tag{I}$$

So, as $\vec {\omega}$ is perpendicular to $\vec r$ the equality (2) is implied.

2) On the other hand if the equality (2) is true it implies

$$r^2 (\vec {\omega} \times \vec r) = (\vec r \times \vec v) \times \vec r = \vec v \ r^2 - \vec r (\vec v \cdot \vec r). \tag{II}$$

So, if your equality (2) is true, and $\vec v$ is defines as tangential velocity, then it implies (1). Therefore if $\vec v$ is defines as tangential velocity, and (1) isn't true, (2) cannot be true, otherwise it would imply that (1) is true.

Comment: I go the second equation from wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions

Comment: it can't be true? why not? and you are saying it doesn't hold...

Comment: @Joseph sorry, I made indeed a mistake in the calculus

Comment: @chuse , yes, thank you, it was a mistake in my calculus. I corrected it.

Comment: I got stuck (and stopped reading) at $\vec{\omega}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}$.  That seems incorrect to me. $\vec{\omega}$ is perp to $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{r}$ is perp to $\vec{v}$, but in general  $\vec{\omega}$ is not  perp to  $\vec{r}$.

Comment: @garyp $\omega = \text d \theta / \text d t$. But $\theta$ is not a vector. How do you define the direction of $\omega$ ? Don't we take it as perpendicular to the plane of rotation? The plane can change during the movement, but I think that in that case we consider the *instant* plane. Another justification: Joseph says that the formula (2) is proved in Wikipedia. But the true formula (2) contains an additional term $-\frac {(\vec r \cdot \vec {\omega})\vec r}{r^2}$. So, probably $\vec {\omega}$ is defined as perp. to $\vec r$.

Comment: @garyp look in the 2nd figure [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_two_dimensions). I hope that it would convince you. I also knew that $\vec {\omega}$ perp. $\vec r$ .

Comment: So are we basically saying that $\vec \omega \times \vec r = \vec v$ is true if $\vec v$ refers to the tangential component? So e.g. it would not hold for an elliptical orbit say where we have a radial component?

Comment: Generally, $\vec{\omega}$ *is not perpendicular to* $\vec{r}$.  Do you mean to say "*if* $\vec{\omega}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}$"?  It seems to me that (1) is always true, and (2) is true only if the origin is in the plane of rotation.

Comment: @garyp I understand what you say, but we are not given here a point from a spinning solid. We are given an orbiting geometric point. Why shouldn't we take the origin outside the orbit plane?

Comment: @garyp : On the other hand, for answering your worries (I hope so), consider two vectors, $\vec r$ at a time $t$, and $\vec r'$ at a time $t' = t + \text d t$, where $\text d t$ is very small. Imagine also a plane passing through the origin and containing these two vectors. Then the "*instantaneous*" $|vec {\omega}$ passes through the origin and is perpendicular to this plane. If the movement of the point is more complicated and the instantaneous plane of movement is not the same all the tie, $\vec {\omega}$ has a precession. Is it O.K. now?

Comment: I think we're ok, but I take a different point of view:  the origin should be arbitrary.  Your analysis works only for a special choice of origin.

Comment: @garyp the origin is a matter of choice. And in practice we choose what simplifies mostly our equations.

Comment: For solving a particular system, yes, we choose the origin to simplify.  But that is not germane to  the OP's question.  The answer to his question is: for uniform motion  (1) is always correct, (2) is correct only if the origin is in the plane of rotation.

Comment: @garyp I don't understand you. I repeat, for instantaneous movement $\vec {\omega}$ is perpendicular, by definition, on the plane comprising the vectors $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$. When I say that the plane comprises the vectors, of course it comprises their origin, which is common to both.

Comment: If my origin is the center of the earth, and I'm interested in the velocity of New York city, $\vec{\omega}$ is not perpendicular to $\vec{r}$.  Your analysis is limited to a special case.

Comment: @garyp , sorry, it is. As the Earth rotates, would you take two vectors very close in time, and that connect New York with the Earth center? Well, the plane containing these two vectors (including the origin in the Earth's center) is the instantaneous plane of rotation. And the instantaneous $\vec {\omega}$ passes through the Earth' center and it perpendicular to the said plane.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok.  I did not read your comments carefully enough.  W

Comment: I meant to add:  I'll leave it to the OP to accept or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that the formula for angular velocity:
>   $$\dot {\vec r}=\vec \omega \times\vec r \tag{1}$$
>   does not hold in some situations, but the book does not specify what situation so please could you produce a list of when this formula does not hold.

That expression is only true in the case of circular motion. It fails whenever the radial component of velocity is non-zero.

> If this formula does not hold is it also true that:
>   $$\vec \omega= \frac{\vec r \times \vec v}{|\vec r|^2} \tag{2}$$
>   does not hold?

That expression is tautologically true; that's one way the angular velocity of a point mass is defined.

It helps to define a set of unit vectors:
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat r &= \frac {\vec r}{||\vec r||} \\
\hat \omega &= \frac {\vec \omega}{||\vec \omega||} \\
\hat \theta &= \hat \omega \times \hat r
\end{aligned}$$

The above unit vectors are well-defined and are mutually orthogonal so long as $\vec r \times \vec v$ is non-zero. Denoting $r = ||\vec r||$ and $\omega = ||\vec \omega||$, the above yields
$$\vec v = \frac {d\vec r}{dt} = \frac {d}{dt}(r \hat r) = \frac {dr}{dt} \hat r + r \frac {d\hat r}{dt} = \dot r \hat r + r\omega \hat \theta = \frac{\dot r} r \vec r + \vec \omega\times\vec r$$
With this, your equation (1) becomes
$$\vec v = \frac{\dot r} r \vec r + \vec \omega\times\vec r \tag{1'}$$
The above reduces to your equation (1) when $\dot r = 0$.